# How to find duplicate elements in array using for loop in Python?

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a list with duplicate elements:

```
 list_a=[1,2,3,5,6,7,5,2]

 tmp=[]

 for i in list_a:
     if tmp.__contains__(i):
         print i
     else:
         tmp.append(i)
```

I have used the above code to find the duplicate elements in the `list_a`. I don't want to remove the elements from list.

But I want to use for loop here.
Normally C/C++ we use like this I guess:

```
 for (int i=0;i<=list_a.length;i++)
     for (int j=i+1;j<=list_a.length;j++)
         if (list_a[i]==list_a[j])
             print list_a[i]
```

how do we use like this in Python?

```
for i in list_a:
    for j in list_a[1:]:
    ....
```

I tried the above code. But it gets solution wrong. I don't know how to increase the value for `j`.

Answer (score 66):

Just for information, In python 2.7+, we can use Counter

```
import collections

x=[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2]

>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2]

>>> y=collections.Counter(x)
>>> y
Counter({2: 2, 5: 2, 1: 1, 3: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1})
```

Unique List

```
>>> list(y)
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

Items found more than 1 time

```
>>> [i for i in y if y[i]>1]
[2, 5]
```

Items found only one time

```
>>> [i for i in y if y[i]==1]
[1, 3, 6, 7]
```

Comment: `[n for n, i in y.iteritems() if i > 1]` instead, and `i == 1`.

Comment: ...but why the list(y), isn't Counter iterable ?

Comment: @Roger Pate, thanks, yours is no need to do dict lookup, it could be better.

Comment: The only drawbacks of Counter is that it doesn't terminate early if duplicates are found early in a big list and it doesn't work for infinite iterator.

Comment: My solution: 
    for k, v in x.most_common():
        if v > 1:
            print k

Answer (score 27):

Use the `in` operator instead of calling `__contains__` directly.

What you have almost works (but is O(n**2)):

```
for i in xrange(len(list_a)):
  for j in xrange(i + 1, len(list_a)):
    if list_a[i] == list_a[j]:
      print "duplicate:", list_a[i]
```

But it's far easier to use a set (roughly O(n) due to the hash table):

```
seen = set()
for n in list_a:
  if n in seen:
    print "duplicate:", n
  else:
    seen.add(n)
```

Or a dict, if you want to track locations of duplicates (also O(n)):

```
import collections
items = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i, item in enumerate(list_a):
  items[item].append(i)
for item, locs in items.iteritems():
  if len(locs) > 1:
    print "duplicates of", item, "at", locs
```

Or even just detect a duplicate somewhere (also O(n)):

```
if len(set(list_a)) != len(list_a):
  print "duplicate"
```

Answer (score 20):

You could always use a list comprehension:

```
dups = [x for x in list_a if list_a.count(x) > 1]
```

Comment: This traverses the list once for each element (Although, OP's code is O(N**2), too).

Comment: Yeah, I understood it's inefficient. If the OP is looking for that, he should go with Roger's answers for sure.

Comment: I think this is slightly more efficient:

[x for i,x in enumerate(list_a) if list_a[i:].count(x) > 1]

Comment: this will return a list with duplicates as well as list_a.count(x) > 1 will return True for each occurence of the element. I'd use set() to get unique duplicates

Answer (score 8):

Before Python 2.3, use dict() :

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2]
>>> stats = {}
>>> for x in lst : # count occurrences of each letter:
...     stats[x] = stats.get(x, 0) + 1 
>>> print stats
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 1} # filter letters appearing more than once:
>>> duplicates = [dup for (dup, i) in stats.items() if i > 1] 
>>> print duplicates
```

So a function :

```
def getDuplicates(iterable):
    """
       Take an iterable and return a generator yielding its duplicate items.
       Items must be hashable.

       e.g :

       >>> sorted(list(getDuplicates([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2])))
       [2, 5]
    """
    stats = {}
    for x in iterable : 
        stats[x] = stats.get(x, 0) + 1
    return (dup for (dup, i) in stats.items() if i > 1)
```

With Python 2.3 comes set(), and it's even a built-in after than :

```
def getDuplicates(iterable):
    """
       Take an iterable and return a generator yielding its duplicate items.
       Items must be hashable.

       e.g :

       >>> sorted(list(getDuplicates([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2])))
       [2, 5]
    """
    try: # try using built-in set
        found = set() 
    except NameError: # fallback on the sets module
        from sets import Set
        found = Set()

    for x in iterable:
        if x in found : # set is a collection that can't contain duplicate
            yield x
        found.add(x) # duplicate won't be added anyway
```

With Python 2.7 and above, you have the **`collections` module providing the very same function than the dict one**, and we can make it shorter (and faster, it's probably C under the hood) than solution 1 :

```
import collections

def getDuplicates(iterable):
    """
       Take an iterable and return a generator yielding its duplicate items.
       Items must be hashable.

       e.g :

       >>> sorted(list(getDuplicates([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2])))
       [2, 5]
    """
    return (dup for (dup, i) in collections.counter(iterable).items() if i > 1)
```

I'd stick with solution 2.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this function to find duplicates:

```py
def get_duplicates(arr):
    dup_arr = arr[:]
    for i in set(arr):
        dup_arr.remove(i)       
    return list(set(dup_arr))
```

### Examples

```py
print get_duplicates([1,2,3,5,6,7,5,2])
```

> [2, 5]

```py
print get_duplicates([1,2,1,3,4,5,4,4,6,7,8,2])
```

> [1, 2, 4]

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for one-to-one mapping between your nested loops and Python, this is what you want:

```
n = len(list_a)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        if list_a[i] == list_a[j]:
            print list_a[i]
```

The code above is not "Pythonic".  I would do it something like this:

```
seen = set()
for i in list_a:
   if i in seen:
       print i
   else:
       seen.add(i)
```

Also, don't use `__contains__`, rather, use `in` (as above).

Answer (score 2):

The following requires the elements of your list to be hashable (not just implementing `__eq__` ).
I find it more pythonic to use a defaultdict (and you have the number of repetitions for free):

```
import collections
l = [1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3]
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for x in l:
   d[x] += 1
print [k for k, v in d.iteritems() if v > 1]
# prints [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using only itertools, and works fine on Python 2.5

```
from itertools import groupby
list_a = sorted([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 2])
result = dict([(r, len(list(grp))) for r, grp in groupby(list_a)])
```

Result:

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a list (`list_a`) potentially including duplicates, which you would rather keep as it is, and build a de-duplicated list `tmp` based on list_a. In Python 2.7, you can accomplish this with one line:

`tmp = list(set(list_a))`

Comparing the lengths of `tmp` and `list_a` at this point should clarify if  there were indeed duplicate items in `list_a`. This may help simplify things if you want to go into the loop for additional processing.

Answer (score 0):

You could just "translate" it line by line.

c++

```
for (int i=0;i<=list_a.length;i++)
    for (int j=i+1;j<=list_a.length;j++)
        if (list_a[i]==list_a[j])
            print list_a[i]
```

Python

```
for i in range(0, len(list_a)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(list_a))
        if list_a[i] == list_a[j]:
            print list_a[i]
```

c++ for loop:

```
for(int x = start; x < end; ++x)
```

Python equivalent:

```
for x in range(start, end):
```

Comment: You should not accept this answer. Yes, it's valid code, but it's not the way you should code in Python. Don't code Python like C/C++, or Java. They are not the same languages, and are not meant to be used the same way.

Comment: I agree with e-satis, although the the question specifically tries to compare the routine to C/C++ we should try to nudge it in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
count,value = np.histogram(list_a,bins=np.hstack((np.unique(list_a),np.inf)))
print 'duplicate value(s) in list_a: ' + ', '.join([str(v) for v in value[count>1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just quick and dirty,

```
list_a=[1,2,3,5,6,7,5,2] 
holding_list=[]

for x in list_a:
    if x in holding_list:
        pass
    else:
        holding_list.append(x)

print holding_list
```

## Output [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]

Answer (score 0):

In case of Python3 and if you two lists

```
def removedup(List1,List2):
    List1_copy = List1[:]
        for i in List1_copy:
            if i in List2:
                List1.remove(i)

List1 = [4,5,6,7]
List2 = [6,7,8,9]
removedup(List1,List2)
print (List1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Granted, I haven't done tests, but I guess it's going to be hard to beat pandas in speed:

```
 pd.DataFrame(list_a, columns=["x"]).groupby('x').size().to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
b=['E', 'P', 'P', 'E', 'O', 'E']
c={}
for i in b:
    value=0
    for j in b:
        if(i == j):
            value+=1
            c[i]=value
print(c)
```

Output:

```
{'E': 3, 'P': 2, 'O': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find duplicates in the list using loops, conditional logic, logical operators, and list methods

```
some_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','b','n','n','c','c','h',]

duplicates = [] 

for values in some_list:

    if some_list.count(values) > 1:

        if values not in duplicates:

            duplicates.append(values)

print("Duplicate Values are : ",duplicates)
```

Comment: How to get this without using any python library such as count?@Zaheer

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
list_a=[1,2,3,5,6,7,5,2]
unique_values = []
duplicates = []

for i in list_a:
    if i not in unique_values:
        unique_values.append(i)
    else:
        found = False
        for x in duplicates:
            if x.get("key") == i:
                found = True
        if found:
            x["occurrence"] += 1
        else:
            duplicates.append({
                "key": i,
                "occurrence": 1
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the number of repeating elements in a list:

```py
myList = [3, 2, 2, 5, 3, 8, 3, 4, 'a', 'a', 'f', 4, 4, 1, 8, 'D']
listCleaned = set(myList)
for s in listCleaned:
    count = 0
    for i in myList:
        if s == i :
            count += 1
    print(f'total {s} => {count}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some_string= list(input("Enter any string:\n"))
count={}
dup_count={}
for i in some_string:
    if i not in count:
        count[i]=1
    else:
        count[i]+=1
        dup_count[i]=count[i]
print("Duplicates of given string are below:\n",dup_count)
```

Answer (score -2):

A little bit more Pythonic implementation (not the most, of course), but in the spirit of your C code could be:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(seq):
    if elem in seq[i+1:]:
        print elem
```

**Edit:** yes, it prints the elements more than once if there're more than 2 repetitions, but that's what the op's C pseudo code does too.

Comment: You must sort before doing that. Use sorted. What's more, you will print the same duplicate several times if there is more than one of the same.

Comment: This will print the same element multiple times if it occurs more than 2 times in the list.

Comment: Have you guys bothered to read the op's code? It does the exactly the same. @e-satis There's no need to sort, maybe you meant something like `[k for k, it in itertools.groupby(sorted(l)) if len(list(it)) > 1]` ?