# Identify duplicate values in a list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

Is it possible to get which values are duplicates in a list using python?

I have a list of items:

```
    mylist = [20, 30, 25, 20]
```

I know the best way of removing the duplicates is `set(mylist)`, but is it possible to know what values are being duplicated? As you can see, in this list the duplicates are the first and last values. `[0, 3]`.

Is it possible to get this result or something similar in python? I'm trying to avoid making a ridiculously big `if elif` conditional statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find duplicate elements in array using for loop in python like c/c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920145/how-to-find-duplicate-elements-in-array-using-for-loop-in-python-like-c-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and list duplicates in Python list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/find-and-list-duplicates-in-python-list)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

These answers are O(n), so a little more code than using `mylist.count()` but much more efficient as `mylist` gets longer

If you just want to know the duplicates, use collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = [20, 30, 25, 20]
[k for k,v in Counter(mylist).items() if v>1]
```

If you need to know the indices,

```
from collections import defaultdict
D = defaultdict(list)
for i,item in enumerate(mylist):
    D[item].append(i)
D = {k:v for k,v in D.items() if len(v)>1}
```

Comment: You could do this with the more compact `[i for key in (key for key, count in Counter(mylist).items() if count > 1) for i, x in enumerate(mylist) if x == key]` - although it's a bit of a monster, you might want to separate out the generator expression.

Comment: You could make `def indices(seq, values):`, `return (i for value in values for i, x in enumerate(seq) if x == value)`, then do `indices(mylist, (key for key, count in Counter(mylist).items() if count > 1)`. That's pretty neat (when not crammed into a comment).

Answer (score 20):

Here's a list comprehension that does what you want. As @Codemonkey says, the list starts at index 0, so the indices of the duplicates are 0 and 3.

```
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(mylist) if mylist.count(x) > 1]
[0, 3]
```

Comment: That's O(n^2)... You can do better.

Comment: @Levon, it does search the whole list

Comment: For those that don't understand what O(N^2) means: it means that for a 10 element list, you'll be executing 100 steps, for 1000 elements 1 milllion steps, for 1 million elements a million million steps, etc. Quadratic performance will kill your performance very rapidly.

Answer (score 10):

You can use list compression and set to reduce the complexity.

```
my_list = [3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1]
opt = [item for item in set(my_list) if my_list.count(item) > 1]
```

Answer (score 7):

The following list comprehension will yield the duplicate values:

```
[x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) >= 2]
```

Comment: This gives the duplicate values, not their indices

Comment: @Junuxx: Although he does mention the indices, he asks for the values, not the indices.

Comment: "As you can see, in this list the duplicates are the first and last values. [0, 3]" seems to indicate the desired output.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this has brackets around it either. This is also far less efficient than using a `Counter`.

Comment: 1) "Is it possible to get which values are duplicates in a list using python?" 2) "is it possible to know what values are being duplicated?" If what he wants are the indices, he is really bad about asking for them.

Comment: @Lattyware: It is the syntax for a set comprehension.

Comment: @Swiss No, it isn't. A set comprehension only requires the curly braces, the brackets here are totally useless.

Comment: @Lattyware: I was confused because `{` is a bracket, but `(` is a parenthesis. You are correct about them being unnecessary then.

Comment: Sorry, that's because I'm in the UK - `()` are usually called *brackets* here, with `[]` and `{}` being *square brackets* and *curly brackets* respectively.

Comment: @Swiss I'm not a native speaker, I learned over time `[` -> (square) braket, `(` -> parenthesis, `{` -> (curly) braces in the US .. :)

Comment: I tried what was written. It did not work. `>>> {x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) >= 2}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    {x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) >= 2} 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`  I changed the braces to square brackets to make a list comprehension. That printed the duplicate values. I looked up set comprehension syntax, and what was written might have worked. 
         ^

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Set comprehensions were added in Python 2.7, so it won't work if you are using a version older than that.

Comment: Note that this has a *terrible* performance profile. `list.count()` is a O(N) job (all elements in the list are compared to count) and you are doing this in a loop over N elements, giving you quadratic performance, O(N^2). So for a 10-element list 100 steps are executed, for a 1000 element list 1 million, etc.

Answer (score 5):

simplest way without any intermediate list using list.index():

```
z = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', ]
[z[i] for i in range(len(z)) if i == z.index(z[i])]
>>>['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and you can also list the duplicates itself (may contain duplicates again as in the example):

```
[z[i] for i in range(len(z)) if not i == z.index(z[i])]
>>>['a', 'b', 'a']
```

or their index:

```
[i for i in range(len(z)) if not i == z.index(z[i])]
>>>[2, 4, 5]
```

or the duplicates as a list of 2-tuples of their index (referenced to their first occurrence only), **what is the answer to the original question!!!**:

```
[(i,z.index(z[i])) for i in range(len(z)) if not i == z.index(z[i])]
>>>[(2, 0), (4, 1), (5, 0)]
```

or this together with the item itself:

```
[(i,z.index(z[i]),z[i]) for i in range(len(z)) if not i == z.index(z[i])]
>>>[(2, 0, 'a'), (4, 1, 'b'), (5, 0, 'a')]
```

or any other combination of elements and indices....

Answer (score 3):

I tried below code to find duplicate values from list

1) create a set of duplicate list

2) Iterated through set by looking in duplicate list.

```
glist=[1, 2, 3, "one", 5, 6, 1, "one"]
x=set(glist)
dup=[]
for c in x:
    if(glist.count(c)>1):
        dup.append(c)
print(dup)
```

**OUTPUT**

> [1, 'one']

Now get the all index for duplicate element

```
glist=[1, 2, 3, "one", 5, 6, 1, "one"]
x=set(glist)
dup=[]
for c in x:
    if(glist.count(c)>1):
        indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(glist) if x == c]
        dup.append((c,indices))
print(dup)
```

**OUTPUT**

> [(1, [0, 6]), ('one', [3, 7])]

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

That's the simplest way I can think for finding duplicates in a list:

```
my_list = [3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1]

my_list.sort()
for i in range(0,len(my_list)-1):
               if my_list[i] == my_list[i+1]:
                   print str(my_list[i]) + ' is a duplicate'
```

Comment: If items appear more than twice you'll print those multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will fetch you desired results with duplicate items and their index values.

```
  for i in set(mylist):
    if mylist.count(i) > 1:
         print(i, mylist.index(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sort the list:

```
mylist.sort()
```

After this, iterate through it like this:

```
doubles = []
for i, elem in enumerate(mylist):
    if i != 0:
        if elem == old:
            doubles.append(elem)
            old = None
            continue
    old = elem
```

Comment: This doesn't get the indices of the items, which the asker appears to want. Also, creating an empty list and looping through items to append some is an anti-pattern in Python, use a list comprehension.

Comment: This too will print items that appear more than twice multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can print duplicate and Unqiue using below logic using list.

```
def dup(x):
    duplicate = []
    unique = []
    for i in x:
        if i in unique:
            duplicate.append(i)
        else:
            unique.append(i)
    print("Duplicate values: ",duplicate)
    print("Unique Values: ",unique)

list1 = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 5]
dup(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [20, 30, 25, 20]

kl = {i: mylist.count(i) for i in mylist if mylist.count(i) > 1 }

print(kl)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the indices of the duplicates. Here is some short code that will find those in O(n) time, without using any packages:

```
dups = {}
[dups.setdefault(v, []).append(i) for i, v in enumerate(mylist)]
dups = {k: v for k, v in dups.items() if len(v) > 1}
# dups now has keys for all the duplicate values
# and a list of matching indices for each

# The second line produces an unused list. 
# It could be replaced with this:
for i, v in enumerate(mylist):
    dups.setdefault(v, []).append(i)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
m = len(mylist)
for index,value in enumerate(mylist):
        for i in xrange(1,m):
                if(index != i):
                    if (L[i] == L[index]):
                        print "Location %d and location %d has same list-entry:  %r" % (index,i,value)
```

This has some redundancy that can be improved however.

Answer (score -2):

```
def checkduplicate(lists): 
 a = []
 for i in lists:
    if  i in a:
        pass   
    else:
        a.append(i)
 return i          
            
print(checkduplicate([1,9,78,989,2,2,3,6,8]))
```

Comment: This prints out the last value in the list. Even if you correct it to `return a`, that removes the duplicates, but the question was "*is it possible to know what values are being duplicated*"