# Repetition inside of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to build a function that will return True if any two items in a list are the same.

For example, `[1,7,3,7,4]` should return `True` and `["one","ONE","One"]` should return `False`.

I need help with which parts of python look for duplicates.

Comment: Related: [Identify duplicate values in a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11236006)

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the values and use a `set` to track what you have already seen. As soon as you see a value *again*, return `True`:

```
def has_duplicates(lst):
    seen = set()
    for elem in lst:
        if elem in seen:
            return True
        seen.add(elem)
    return False
```

This is very efficient in that it short-circuits; it won't loop over the whole list if a duplicate has been detected early on.

Comment: Wouldn't a list be faster? (`seen = []`) I did a quick `timeit` (`timeit.timeit("s.add(5)", "s = set()")` was `0.100...` and `timeit.timeit("s.append(5)", "s = []")` was `0.0911`)

Comment: Why not just do: `if len(set(lst)) != len(lst)`

Comment: @RPGillespie Because that has to iterate over the whole list.

Comment: @Reticality because `set(lst)` iterates over the whole list to produce the set. No, using a list for `seen` is going to be *slower*. Don't compare appending speed of sets and lists here, it is *membership testing* that'll kill you, as it is O(N) for lists vs. O(1) for sets. The larger the number of unique values the slower testing against the list is going to be.

Answer (score 1):

Martijn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28678384/4099593) is the best, but with a few exceptions, this is worth a try.

```
>>> chk = lambda x: len(l) != len(set(l)) # check the length after removing dupes. 
>>> l = [1,7,3,7,4] 
>>> chk(l)
True
>>> l = ["one","ONE","One"]
>>> chk(l)
False
```

*Note* - As [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678337/repetition-inside-of-lists/28678422?noredirect=1#comment45649931_28678422) mentions in a comment, this is a slower process.

Comment: This requires iteration over the *whole* list. Try this out with `[1] + list(range(1000000))` for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yep, It is a very slow way to do!. :) (But hopefully not a *wrong* way)

Answer (score 1):

Using a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict:

```
from collections import Counter
def has_dupes(l):
    # if most repeated key count is > 1 we have at least one dupe
    return Counter(l).most_common(1)[0][1] > 1
```

Or use `any`:

```
def has_dupes(l):
    return any(v > 1 for v in Counter(l).values())
```

Comment: This is slower still than using `len(set(l))` as it requires a O(N) loop over all the values, followed by creating a heap to find the most common element, again O(N). Asymptotically the same as `len(set(l))` but with a higher fixed cost per iteration.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes, but a linear solution, another example of how to do what the OP wants and an introduction to a Counter dict which is a pretty useful tool. If the question was what is the optimal way because I have a huge amount of data then that would be different but it's not.

Comment: I'm merely commenting on the performance aspects of the solution, because I do think that matters. Otherwise this whole question would just be a dupe of [Identify duplicate values in a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11236006)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, fair enough but  I don't think in this case performance is a concern at all.  `has_dupes([1] + list(range(1000000)))` takes `249ms`
`

Comment: If it is no concern we may as well dupe this. But there is a *generic* use here for future visitors. Some of those may well be concerned with performance.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. I am not disputing the extra work in mine I just don't think the OP is overly concerned with performance, I also don't think the title does either.

Comment: But all the solutions here *echo the other post*. My point being that if you *only* need to know *if* there is a duplicate, then you can use a single loop and exit early. Otherwise just use any of the techniques in the dupe and turn that into a boolean.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, well all bar one of the related questions are not exactly great answers. There are n log n and quadratic solutions and the accepted answer use items instead of most_common or just the values, would you recommend `if mylist.count(x) > 1`?

Comment: `mylist.count(x) > 1` is terrible. I didn't say the options in that post were all that great. But the accepted answer is correct if you wanted to know *which* elements were duplicated.