# Find Duplicates in large dataset using python

Tags: python, optimization, duplicates, largenumber

I want to find duplicates from a large json file(12gb) in python. 
Now I read the whole file, use set() as a look up table and store unique values and then write the duplicates to a file.

But if the input data is of 100gb, the set() will not be able to handle the unique values and hence my code is not scalabe.

Any idea how I can do it alternatively?

Using python

```
import json
import time

""" This calss contains the business logic for identifying the duplicates and creating an output file for further processing """

class BusinessService:

    """ The method identiifes the duplicate """

    def service(ipPath,opPath):
        start_time = time.time()    #We start the timer 
        uniqueHandleSet = set();     #Creating a set to store unique values #

        try:
            # Opening and creating an output file to catch the duplicate hanndles #                     
            duplicateHandles = open(opPath,'w+',encoding='utf-8') 
            #Reading the JSON File by buffering and using 20mb as it is too big to read at once #       
            with open(ipPath,buffering = 200000000, encoding = 'utf-8') as infile:     
                for line in infile:
                    tweetJsonObject = json.loads(line);
                    if tweetJsonObject["name"] not in uniqueHandleSet:
                        uniqueHandleSet.add(tweetJsonObject["name"]);
                    else:
                        duplicateHandles.write(line);  
            print("--- %s seconds --- memory 200mb while buffering" % (time.time() - start_time));  #Printing the total time required to execute 
        except:
            print("Error")

        finally:
            duplicateHandles.close();
```

I need to use an alternative for set() for the lookup

Comment: Why is `set()` not handling your situation?  Are you running out of memory from the size of the set object?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, but look that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44191465/efficiently-identify-duplicates-in-large-list-500-000)

Comment: Have you looked into using something like map-reduce from PySpark?

Comment: Hey James, the problem with set() is that it wont be able to store enough in-memory data if the input file is 100gb+ and I did not venture into PySpark becaus it requires me to use native python libraries but pySpark would require my laptop to have spark, hadoop environment as well right?

Comment: Are you willing and able to work with a database? You will almost certainly need one for 100+ GB of data. Moreover, you will almost certainly need to batch-process the DB data back to JSON. If this is in your wheelhouse, someone can help.

Comment: Actually its a challenge that I have participated in, my code works efficiently on a 12gb fiile since the set() can handle it, but it needs to be scaled so that it can handle a 100gb file where the set() wont work for a lookup. Would you recommend me using database or something like pyspark where I can use the RDD for lookup