# finding non-unique elements in list not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wanted to find the non-unique elements in the list, but I am not able to figure out why this is not happening in the below code section.

```
>>> d = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 6,'f',3]
>>> for i in d:
...     if d.count(i) == 1:
...             d.remove(i)
... 
>>> d
[1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 6, 3]
```

6 and 3 should have been removed. 
where as, if I use

```
d = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

I am getting correct answer. Please explain what is happening, I am confused !!!

I am using python 2.7.5.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Removing elements of a list while iterating over it is never a good idea. The appropriate way to do this would be to use a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 6, 'f', 3]
>>> # Use items() instead of iteritems() in Python 3
>>> [k for (k,v) in Counter(d).iteritems() if v > 1]
['a', 1, 2, 'b', 4]
```

If you want keep the duplicate elements in the order in which they appear in your list:

```
>>> keep = {k for (k,v) in Counter(d).iteritems() if v > 1}
>>> [x for x in d if x in keep]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

---

I'll try to explain why your approach doesn't work. To understand why some elements aren't removed as they should be, imagine that we want to remove all `b`s from the list `[a, b, b, c]` while looping over it. It'll look something like this:

```
+-----------------------+
|  a  |  b  |  b  |  c  |
+-----------------------+
   ^ (first iteration)

+-----------------------+
|  a  |  b  |  b  |  c  |
+-----------------------+
         ^ (next iteration: we found a 'b' -- remove it)

+-----------------------+
|  a  |     |  b  |  c  |
+-----------------------+
         ^ (removed b)

+-----------------+
|  a  |  b  |  c  |
+-----------------+
         ^ (shift subsequent elements down to fill vacancy)

+-----------------+
|  a  |  b  |  c  |
+-----------------+
               ^ (next iteration)
```

Notice that we skipped the second `b`! Once we removed the first `b`, elements were shifted down and our `for`-loop consequently failed to touch every element of the list. The same thing happens in your code.

Comment: thanks. Using Counter it is working but why that piece of code isn't working. I want to know what is the problem in it ?!

Comment: by the way I want the answer to be [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'] not ['a',1,2,'b',4]. if I use the elements() method in Counter in your code for getting this answer will make the list sorted which i do not want !!

Comment: @tanmay See the edit (by the way was 5 a typo? why should 5 be in that list?).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, at least I knew now what is happening !!:)

Comment: sorry 5 will not be in the list !!! my copying mistake !! The answer should be  [1,2,1,2,4,4,'a','b','a','b'], i.e., all repetitive or non-unique elements including their repetitions and order maintained

Comment: Using Python 3.5.3 the suggested solution returns an error: `AttributeError: 'Counter' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`. Instead of `iteritems()` I use `items()` which works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

Better use [collections.Counter()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
>>> d = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 6,'f',3]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [k for k, v in Counter(d).iteritems() if v > 1]
['a', 1, 2, 'b', 4]
```

Also see relevant thread:

- [How to find duplicate elements in array using for loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920145/how-to-find-duplicate-elements-in-array-using-for-loop-in-python-like-c-c)

Answer (score 3):

I just thought I would add my method with set comprehension if anyone was interested.

```
>>> d = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 6,'f',3]
>>> d = list({x for x in d if d.count(x) > 1})
>>> print d
['a', 1, 2, 'b', 4]
```

Python 2.7 and up I believe for the set comprehension functionality.

Comment: please **don't use this method**, it has `O(n^2)` complexity

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the answers and comments !

Thought for a while and got another answer in my previous way I have written the code. So, I am posting it.

```
d = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 6,'f',3]
e = d[:] # just a bit of trick/spice
>>> for i in d:
...     if d.count(i) == 1:
...             e.remove(i)
... 
>>> e
[1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

@arshajii, Your explanation led me to this trick. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this :

```
data=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,1,5,6]
    first_list=[]
    second_list=[]
    for i in data:
        if data.count(i)==1:
            first_list.append(i)
        else:
            second_list.append(i)
            print (second_list)
```

## Result

[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]

Answer (score 0):

For

```
>>> d = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 6,'f',3]
```

Using conversion to a set yields the unique items:

```
>>> d_unique = list(set(d))
```

Non-unique items can be found using a list comprehension

```
>>> [item for item in d_unique if d.count(item) >1]
[1, 2, 4, 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

In python3 , use `dict.items()` instead of `dict.iteritems()`

`iteritems()` was removed in python3, so you can't use this method anymore.

```
    >>> d = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 6,'f',3]
    >>> from collections import Counter
    >>> [k for k, v in Counter(d).items() if v > 1]
    ['a', 1, 2, 'b', 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

To also get the values (key, value), use `dict` instead of `list` comprehension:

```py
from collections import Counter


d = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 6,'f',3]
{k: v for k, v in Counter(d).items() if v > 1}
```