# Adding up contents of list - project euler 1

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm trying to do Project Euler Problem 1 in Python (http://projecteuler.net./problem=1) and I'm using a while loop to loop to 1000:

```
from collections import Counter

x = 0
target = 1000
correctMultiples = list()
while x < target:
    x += 1
    if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0:
        correctMultiples.append(x)

print(str(correctMultiples) + ' are multiples of 3 or 5')

print('The sum of the multiples of 3 or 5 under 1000 is, ' + str(sum(correctMultiples))) # For some reason, 1000 over, answer is 233168 NOT 234168
```

This works but the answer I'm getting is 1000 over. I get 234168 instead of 233168.

I've tried checking for duplicates: (following [How to find duplicate elements in array using for loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920145/how-to-find-duplicate-elements-in-array-using-for-loop-in-python-like-c-c))

```
duplicates = Counter(correctMultiples)
print([i for i in duplicates if duplicates[i] > 1])
```

but I don't think there can be duplicates can they? becuase I'm using if x % 3  **or** ...

I know this isn't the most efficient method, but still... why doesn't it work?
Can anyone help me find why the answer is 1000 over?
Thanks

Comment: Hint: is 1000 divisible by 3 or 5?

Comment: worth noting that if you want to get rid of duplicates you can simply `list(set(myList))`

Comment: you might want to check `range()` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You include `1000` in your loop, while the question ask for numbers *below* 1000.

Here you increment after doing the boundary check, so when `x==999` you will still run the loop:

```
while x < target:
    x += 1
```

This would be so much easier with a `for` loop:

```
for x in range(1000):
```

[range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) does *not* include the last element.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Python - when I say <, does it include the number?

Comment: No, but you increment `x` *after* you do that check.

Answer (score 0):

You are including the number 1000 in your loop, because in the last iteration, `x` is 999 and gets increased once more.

A better solution would be the construct

```
for x in range(1,1000):
    ...
```

which includes all x from 1 to 999 and doesn't compare to 1000 on each iteration.