# Get a unique list of items that occur more than once in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of items:

```
mylist = ['A','A','B','C','D','E','D']
```

I want to return a unique list of items that appear more than once in mylist, so that my desired output would be:

```
 [A,D]
```

Not sure how to even being this, but my though process is to first append a count of each item, then remove anything equal to 1. Then dedupe, but this seems like a really roundabout, inefficient way to do it, so I am looking for advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find duplicate elements in array using for loop in python like c/c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920145/how-to-find-duplicate-elements-in-array-using-for-loop-in-python-like-c-c)

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do what you have described easily:

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = ['A','A','B','C','D','E','D']
cnt = Counter(mylist)
print([k for k, v in cnt.items() if v > 1])
# ['A', 'D']
```

Comment: If anyone is using Python 3, use `items()` as opposed to `iteritems()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418498/852795.

Comment: This now throws a SyntaxError

Comment: @branwen85 Yes, because in Python 3, you need parentheses around the `print` argument. 

`print([k for k, v in cnt.items() if v > 1])` will work.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> mylist = ['A','A','B','C','D','E','D']
>>> set([i for i in mylist if mylist.count(i)>1])
set(['A', 'D'])
```

Comment: For short lists, this is a useful and easily understandable approach. But keep in mind: this solution has quadratic complexity (n*n). The solutions using collections.Counter have a linear (2*n) complexity.

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections
cc = collections.Counter(mylist) # Counter({'A': 2, 'D': 2, 'C': 1, 'B': 1, 'E': 1})
cc.subtract(cc.keys())           # Counter({'A': 1, 'D': 1, 'C': 0, 'B': 0, 'E': 0})
cc += collections.Counter()      # remove zeros (trick from the docs)
print cc.keys()                  # ['A', 'D']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try some thing like this:

```
a = ['A','A','B','C','D','E','D']

import collections
print [x for x, y in collections.Counter(a).items() if y > 1]
 ['A', 'D']
```

Reference: [How to find duplicate elements in array using for loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920145/how-to-find-duplicate-elements-in-array-using-for-loop-in-python-like-c-c)

**OR**

```
def list_has_duplicate_items( mylist ):
    return len(mylist) > len(set(mylist))
def get_duplicate_items( mylist ):
    return [item for item in set(mylist) if mylist.count(item) > 1]
mylist = [ 'oranges' , 'apples' , 'oranges' , 'grapes' ]
print 'List: ' , mylist
print 'Does list have duplicate item(s)? ' , list_has_duplicate_items( mylist )
print 'Redundant item(s) in list: ' , get_duplicate_items( mylist )
```

Reference https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/286996/get-redundant-items-in-list

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 2):

Using a similar approach to others here, heres my attempt:

```
from collections import Counter

    def return_more_then_one(myList):
         counts = Counter(my_list)
         out_list = [i for i in counts if counts[i]>1]
         return out_list
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be as simple as ...

```
print(list(set([i for i in mylist if mylist.count(i) > 1])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use set to help you do that, like this maybe :

```
X = ['A','A','B','C','D','E','D']
Y = set(X)
Z = []

for val in Y :
    occurrences = X.count(val)
    if(occurrences > 1) :
        #print(val,'occurs',occurrences,'times')
        Z.append(val)

print(Z)
```

The list Z will save the list item which occur more than once. And the part I gave comment (#), that will show the number of occurrences of each list item which occur more than once

Answer (score 0):

Might not be as fast as internal implementations, but takes (almost) linear time (since `set` lookup is logarithmic)

```
mylist = ['A','A','B','C','D','E','D']
myset = set()
dups = set()
for x in mylist:
    if x in myset:
        dups.add(x)
    else:
        myset.add(x)
dups = list(dups)
print dups
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution what's written:

```
def delete_rep(list_):
new_list = []
for i in list_:
    if i not in list_[i:]:
        new_list.append(i)

return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach without using packages

```
result = []
for e in listy:
    if listy.count(e) > 1:
        result.append(e)
    else:
        pass
print(list(set(result)))
```